# Visual Studio changed its alphabet

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I was typing quickly and accidentally hit `alt` and some other keys. Because I hit `alt` without realizing it I tried undoing what I'd done but...I don't know. Now I can only write in Cyrillic. What keys did I hit by mistake and how can I change this back?

[image]

Comment: There may have been a cat walking on the keyboard too...

Comment: Looks like I hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left shift</kbd>

http://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows

Comment: I think you font type has been changed so once you go visual studio -> tools -> options ->font and ... -> change the font which you want. try this may be help you

Answer (score 3):

That's not Visual Studio's fault.

When you press ALT+SHIFT you're toggling the current input language in Windows. You can change the available input languages in the "Keyboards and Languages" settings in Windows, or the "Text Services and Input Languages" (both searchable from Start Menu if you're on Vista/7).

Additional help/info on changing your language input settings:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/add-or-change-an-input-language

Comment: apparently it is a Windows thing but on a per application basis. I typed that question while I was still having the problem in VS. Also, I just tried again and get кгыышфт in FF but in Windows explorer I get expected Latin characters.

Comment: I think it's configurable if it's per application or system basis. On my machine it's system-wide. And you can also configure the shortcut keys for the change if Alt+Shift is disturbing.